# Vertical mirror-image of log-normal distribution

Tags: r, probability-density

Is anyone familiar with the PDF that looks like vertical mirror-image of log-normal distribution? What theoretical distribution would that be? How can I generate such a distribution in R?

[image]

Many thanks!

Comment: If you are just mirroring along y-axis, then `g(x) = f(-x)` where `f(x)` is the log-normal distribution.

Comment: or `plot(density(log(runif(10000))))`